# PDF indirect object, CFF resource

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts

I am working with OpenType Minion Pro font (hereafter "The Font"). I am making raw PDF files. I want to use the raw PostScript syntax with letters from various languages like transliteration:

[image]

For example, English text will be:

```
BT /F1.5 11 Tf (ABCDE... abcde...) Tj ET
```

Russian text:

```
BT /F1.6 11 Tf (ABVGD... abvgd...) Tj ET
```

Minuscule numbers:

```
BT /F1.1 11 Tf (1234567890) Tj ET
```

etc.

The question: is it possible to add in a PDF file a **single object with a whole font** and as many language groups, index tables as I need?

Thank you!

Comment: In first line of table I made a typo: `Numbers 1, /F 1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working! It is possible! The single CFF stream object imported from a font and multiple fonts descriptors.
Deflated size of Minion Regular entire CFF table is 106KB. Not too bad.